# error de sintaxis al restaurar una copia de seguridad en psql

Tags: postgresql-9.3

tengo un error en la restauración de una copia de seguridad en postgresql, el error que aparece al intentar hacer el comando de restauración de copia de seguridad es el que puse en el titulo, el comando que uso es el siguiente

```
psql -U postgres -d drogueria < "C:\Users\MattSeidel\Downloads\bk_drogueria.sql";
```

Comment: Si tu base de datos contiene archivos binarios, es posible que este mal respaldada

Comment: no creo, tengo esta base de datos con algunos colegas y ellos si pudieron restaurarla, el único que no pudo fui yo

Comment: pero donde estas poniendo esa instruccion, ya que tienes que estar en la direccion donde esta tu postgres instalado y en la carpeta bin, otro error que puede ser es que la base de datos drogueria ya tenga algo guardado y no coincida con la bd que estas restaurando